# Angular Directive incoming scope value is undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-directive

In html I have this object passed into directive

```
<lcd-code ldcCode="{{ detail.program.ldcCode }}"></lcd-code>
```

detail.program.ldcCode = "PSIH"  ...

However in the Directive it is undefined

```
var lcdCode = function (customerService, $sce) {
    return {
        replace: true,
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            ldcCode: "="  // two way 
        },
         link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            console.log('scope.ldcCode',scope.ldcCode);   // says undefined

         }
    };
}
```

Previously I was using  "@"  and then attrs.ldcCode seemed to work...  I guess the end result of what data I was working with and sending back I figured that I wanted the 2 way data binding.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use without `{{}}` for two way binding

```
<lcd-code ldcCode="detail.program.ldcCode"></lcd-code>
```

Comment: It is still undefined

Comment: `<lcd-code ldcCode="detail.program.ldcCode"></lcd-code>`

Comment: `console.log('scope.ldcCode',scope.ldcCode);`     says  undefined

Comment: @JohnBaxter does your `detail.program.ldcCode` has any value?

Comment: yes    it can spit it out to the page {{ }}  and it shows  PSIH

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to use Expression , remove the **`{{}}`**

```
<lcd-code ldcCode="detail.program.ldcCode"></lcd-code>
```

Comment: It is still undefined without Expression